# Fetching data from one table to another in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, sails.js

I am having a Database in mongo named "sell". Now this DB contains two tables "Car" and "Order". In "Car" table I have attribute named "price". Now when i am executing

```
db.Order.aggregate([ 
{
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "Car",
                        localField: "carId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "PRICE",
                    },
                },
                { $unwind: "$PRICE" },]).pretty()
```

command in mongo shell it gives output containing "Order" table attributes with PRICE array which contains all the attributes of "Car" table. Now, I want to fetch "price" attribute which is in "Car" table. My current output is as shown in link below but I want to fetch "price" from "PRICE". So what should my command be???

My code for "Car" table model is

```
module.exports = {
    tableName: "Car",
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        carmodel: {
            type: "String",
        },
        stock: {
            type: "Number",
        },
        color: {
            model: "Master",
        },
        code: {
            type: "STRING",
            unique: true,
        },
        brakes: {
            type: "String",
        },

        description: {
            type: "String",
        },
        wheels: {
            type: "String",
        },
        carwindow: {
            type: "String",
        },
        carseat: {
            model: "Master",
        },
        engine: {
            type: "String",
        },
        price: {
            type: "Number",
        },
        //self relation
        parentId: {
            model: "Car",
            columnName: "parentId",
        },
        //OTM
        Master: {
            collection: "Master",
            via: "car",
        },
        //OTO
        order: {
            collection: "order",
            via: "carId",
        },
        sellprice: {
            collection: "order",
            via: "price",
        },
    },
};
```

My code for "Order" table is

```
const { date } = require("faker");
const Car = require("../models/Car");

module.exports = {
    tableName: "Order",
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        address: { type: "String" },
        status: {
            model: "Master",
        },
        orderDate: { type: "string", columnType: "datetime" },
        //OTO
        carId: {
            model: "Car",
            unique: true,
        },
        price: {
            model: "Car",
            unique: true,
        },
        //OTM
        Master: {
            collection: "Master",
            via: "order",
        },
    },
};
```

My desired output is

```
{"PRICE" : 905000 }
```

PRICE is total of all cars price in Order

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJYDT.jpg

Comment: Please post some sample data not as an image

Comment: Sample data in terms of code or some data of what output should look like??

Comment: better if you post both

Comment: Sir please do have a look now

Comment: I can help you with query if you post the data only, not how you structured, coz I'm not a nodejs guy. If it's not possible, sometimes someone will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Order.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Car",
            let: { carId: "$carId" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$carId", "$_id"] } } },
                { $project: { price: 1, _id: 0 } },
            ],
            as: "carInfo",
        },
    },
    { $unwind: "$carInfo" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$carInfo" } },
]);
```

Comment: This is not working. I executed it in my mongo shell but no output is displayed. Could you please suggest me some another way?

Comment: check for this $eq:["$$carId","$_id"] are your Ids are same and data type is also same

Comment: There was a bracket missing so I was not getting the output. Now I am getting it, but what if I want to add these outputs and display it as total price??

Comment: db.Order.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Car",
            let: { carId: "$carId" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$carId", "$_id"] } } },
                { $project: { price: 1, _id: 0 } },
            ],
            as: "carInfo",
        },
    },
    { $unwind: "$carInfo" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot:{$mergeObjects:[ "$carInfo",{orderPrice:"$price"}]} } },
    {$addFields:{totalPrice:{$add:["$price","$orderPrice"]}}}
]);

Comment: there are hundreads of ways in mongodb , if u liked my answer please upvote and like

Comment: Yes I already upvoted it when the first query was working. But after executing this new query also the totalPrice is displayed as  null. I want it as total sum of all the prices which are coming from Car table in Order table

Comment: I mean I showed you a way , u can check for syntax and other things , I suggest to use some tool like studio 3T by which you can visualise the pipeline , every stage of pipeline , you need to play around it and eventually you will learn it , its like learning a programming language